# Signed bytecode loading

Tags: security, lua, bytecode

So I'm looking into securing Lua's `load` function for bytecode loading. Currently I have this:

```
local nativeload = load
load = function(chunk, chunkname, mode, ...)
  if mode == nil then
    mode = "bt"
  elseif not (mode == "b" or mode == "t" or mode == "bt") then
    error("Invalid mode")
  end
  local targetenv = [[snip]]
  if select('#', ...) > 0 then targetenv = ... end
  if mode == "t" then
    return nativeload(chunk, chunkname, mode, targetenv)
  elseif type(chunk) == "string" then
    if chunk:sub(1,4) == "\27Lua" then
      local code = chunk:sub(1,-33)
      if HMAC_SHA256(code, getkey()) == chunk:sub(-32) then
        return nativeload(code, chunkname, mode, targetenv)
      else
        error("Invalid signature")
      end
    else
      return nativeload(chunk, chunkname, mode, targetenv)
    end
  elseif type(chunk) == "function" then
    -- How do I do this?!
  end
end
```

And, while text mode and string chunks are fairly trivial to handle, I have no idea how to handle function chunks.

Do I just collect everything into a string somehow, then do the HMAC stuff and call `nativeload` with this string? But then I lose being able to `load()` large files (e.g. 2GB files) without the program crashing (`load` with function compiles the file in 8kbyte increments, and when the file is mostly empty lines, that means it only needs a few kbytes during compilation - while loading the whole file into a string would clearly use 2GB of RAM).

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
local function extract_code(data)
   local code = data:sub(1,-33)
   assert(HMAC_SHA256(code, getkey()) == data:sub(-32), "Invalid signature")
   return code
end

local nativeload = load
load = function(chunk, chunkname, mode, ...)
   local targetenv = [[snip]]
   if select('#', ...) ~= 0 then targetenv = ... end
   local new_chunk
   if type(chunk) == "string" then
      new_chunk = chunk:match"^\27Lua" and extract_code(chunk) or chunk
   elseif type(chunk) == "function" then
      local buffer = ""
      repeat
         local next_part = chunk() or ""
         buffer = buffer..next_part
      until next_part == "" or #buffer >= 4
      if buffer:match"^\27Lua" then -- Bytecode can't be very large, collect it in a string
         local t = {buffer}
         while t[#t] ~= "" do t[#t+1] = chunk() or "" end
         new_chunk = extract_code(table.concat(t))
      else                          -- Source code can be very large, use a function
         local function f()
            f = chunk
            return buffer
         end
         function new_chunk()
            return f()
         end
      end
   end
   return nativeload(new_chunk, chunkname, mode, targetenv)
end
```

Comment: Hey what happened to the text mode optimization? Also you're not supposed to use assert as error as some libraries hook it.

Comment: Also why use O(nlogn) `t[#t+1]` rather than O(n) keeping track of length?

Comment: 1) "text mode optimization" does almost nothing useful for you. 2) Yes, you may want to use some other ways to generate errors.  My code is just an illustration of intercept-the-chunk-function algorithm.

Comment: Yes, you may optimize this code by using function (instead of string) in bytecode case too. But I believe that all Lua bytecode programs are quite small in size.

Comment: Text mode optimization avoids hitting the GC for garbage `string.sub`s and functions

Comment: From manual: `The string mode controls whether the chunk can be text or binary (that is, a precompiled chunk). It may be the string "b" (only binary chunks), "t" (only text chunks), or "bt" (both binary and text). The default is "bt".` Doesn't that imply only those are valid values?

Comment: Lua internally collects whole bytecode in a single memory block (even if it was loaded using function-chunk), that's why bytecode loading optimization in your code will not be useful - total time complexity will be O(nlogn) anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127254/discussion-between-soniex2-and-egor-skriptunoff).